# Listing with `ls` and regular expression

Tags: bash, wildcards

How can I list files with a filename ending with last character and with `.txt` extension ?

I have tried `ls *+([[:digit:]]).txt` but this is true for `abc12.txt` and `abc2.txt`.

But I need to get only `abc2.txt`. How can I do that?

Is there any sort form of `:digit:` that will do this?

Comment: It should be noted pattern is only valid with *extended globbing* endabled: `shopt -s extglob`.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

How about:

```
ls -d -- *[!0-9][0-9].txt
```

The `!` at the beginning of the group complements its meaning.

As noted in the comments, this is bash's doing, try e.g.:

```
printf "%s\n" *[!0-9][0-9].txt
```

Comment: Note that bash (i.e. `ls`) does not support regular expressions here. These are *filename expressions (Globbing)*. You can see the difference already in your example: here, `*` is a wildcard, which is not there in regular expressions, where you would use `.*` to achieve the same. Regular expressions are a lot more powerful than globbing.

Answer (score 31):

The question asked for regular expressions. Bash, and thus `ls`, does not support regular expressions here. What it supports is *filename expressions* ([Globbing](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html)), a form of wildcards. Regular expressions are a lot more powerful than that.

If you really want to use regular expressions, you can use `find -regex` like this:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -regex '\./.*[^0-9][0-9]\.txt'
```

Find is recursive by default, but `ls` is not. To only find files in the current directory, you can disable recursion with `-maxdepth 1`.
Find matches against the filename with path, that's why the filenames start with `./` if you run find in `.`. The regex starts with `\./` to cope with that. Note that in a regex, `.` is a special character matching any character, but here we really want a dot, that's why we escape it with a backslash. We do the same for the dot in `.txt`, because the regex would otherwise also match `Atxt`. The digit classes are same as for globbing, just that you need `^` instead of `!` to invert the character class.

If you want to get the output of `ls`, then you can use `-exec ls` like this:

```
 find . -maxdepth 1 -regex '\./.*[^0-9][0-9]\.txt' -exec ls -lah {} \;
```

`find` supports a couple of different regex flavors. You can specify a `-regextype`, for example:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -regextype egrep -regex '\./.*[^0-9][0-9]\.txt'
```

For me, possible types are:
‘findutils-default’, ‘awk’, ‘egrep’, ‘ed’, ‘emacs’, ‘gnu-awk’, ‘grep’, ‘posix-awk’, ‘posix-basic’, ‘posix-egrep’, ‘posix-extended’, ‘posix-minimal-basic’, ‘sed’
You can run `find -regextype help` to find out what is supported on your system.

Comment: Is the portion `'\./'` really necessary? Seems to work similarly without that part.

Comment: @Rajib In the example regex given above, `\./` is followed by `.*`, which matches any characters, i.e. also `./`. This means in this exact case, it is not necessary. It may be necessary if another pattern is used. Let's say if you want to match all files starting with `a`, then the regex  `\./a.*` would do, but `a.*` would not.

Comment: Wouldn't `-maxdepth  1` always restrict to this directory, i.e. `./ ` ?

Comment: @Rajib Yes. But the regex you pass to `find -regex` always needs to match the whole path. If you pass the regex `a.*`, it is interpreted like `^a.*$`. As all paths here start with `./`, the regex `a.*` can never match, not even to the file called `a`.

Comment: Got it. I was missing the `-regex` bit. I was thinking in terms of globbing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With the ksh extended globs (or `bash -O extglob` or `zsh -o kshglob`) that you're already using, that would be:

```
ls -d -- ?(*[![:digit:]])[[:digit:]].txt
```

Or

```
ls -d -- !(*[[:digit:]])[[:digit:]].txt
```

If you want to match on `a1.txt` **and `2.txt`** but not `a12.txt` nor `12.txt`.

However note that in ksh and bash (unless you set the `failglob` option to get a behaviour similar to zsh's), if that pattern doesn't match any file, the pattern will be passed literally to `ls`, and if that (strangely named) file happens to exist, it will be listed by `ls` even though it doesn't match the pattern itself.

To include `.2.txt`, set the `dotglob` option in `bash`, add the `(D)` glob qualifier in `zsh`, or set `FIGNORE` to `!(.|..)` in `ksh93`.